# ld reports undefined reference to symbol found by nm

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am building a shared library with the following instructions :

```
cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy.so.0 [lots of .o files] -o libmy.so.0
ln -f -s libmy.so.0 libmy.so
```

I don't know if this is important, but this library is written in C.

I then try to link with this library, from a C++ program :

```
/usr/bin/c++ -g CMakeFiles/codegen.dir/client/codegen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/codegen.dir
 /namenode/shared_objects.cpp.o  -o codegen -rdynamic -L/path/to/libmy -lpthread
 -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt
 -lboost_serialization-mt -lmy -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/libmy
```

But ld reports an error :

```
CMakeFiles/codegen.dir/client/codegen.cpp.o: In function `main':
[...]/src/client/codegen.cpp:46:
   undefined reference to `alloc_code(int, int, int, int, int)'
```

Even if `alloc_code` appears to be in the shared library:

```
$ nm libmy.so | grep alloc_code
0000000000002c80 T alloc_code
```

Note that `libmy.so` and my `codegen` program are compiled using different compiler flags (one is compiled in debug mode while the other is compiled in optimized mode), but I don't think the issue comes from here.

What could make `ld` unable to link `codegen` with `libmy.so` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C function needs to be declared to C++ as this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void alloc_code(int, int, int, int, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Otherwise, the compiler and thus linker assume C++ linkage (where multiple functions can exist with the same name so long as their arguments differ) - and will search for the "C++-mangled" variant of the function.

When using `extern "C"` you tell the compiler and linker to use the unmangled "C" name.

To demonstrate this, let's write the same "library" and compile it with both a C compiler and a C++ compiler:

```
/* Library Source Code */
int library_function(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile with C:

```
gcc -o libdummy.so -shared -fPIC dummy-library.c
nm libdummy.so | grep library_function
```

Which outputs:

```
0000000000000640 T library_function
```

Running the same thing with a C++ compiler yields:

```
g++ -o libdummy.so -shared -fPIC dummy-library.c
nm libdummy.so
```

=>

```
0000000000000670 T _Z16library_functionv
```

Comment: Note that the `#ifdef __cplusplus` is just there so that C compilers reading the header don't get confused.

Comment: Thanks a million, this solved my issue. I though the linking process/linking interfaces were universal.